# The image upload into the DB table and public folder of my Laravel 6 application isn't working

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on Laravel registration form. The form uploads user profile image with validation. This image should be inserted into both **attachments table in database, and public folder in PhpStorm.**

Here are the code I have done but doesn't work at all. Any help, is highly appreciated.

Upload file controller:

```
class UploadFileController extends Controller
{

public function store($request)
{
    $attachment = new Attachment();
    $attachment->mime = $request->mime;
    $attachment->size = $request->size;
    $attachment->name = $request->name;
    $attachment->original_name = $request->original_name;
    $attachment->attachment_type = $request->attachment_type;
    $attachment->attachment_id = $request->attachment_id;
    $attachment->save();
    return $attachment;
}

public function action(Request $request)
{

    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'file' => '
        required|image|mimes:jpeg, png, jpg, gif|max:2048'
    ]);
    if($validation->passes())
    {
        $image = $request->file('file');
        $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move(public_path('/files'), $new_name );
        return response()->json([
            'message'        => 'File Uploaded Successfully',
            'uploaded_image' => '<img src="/files/'.$new_name.'" class="img-thumbnail" width="300" />',
            'class_name'   => 'alert-success'
        ]);
    }
    else
    {
        return response()->json([
            'message'        => $validation->errors()->all(),
            'uploaded_image'   => '',
            'class_name'     => 'alert_danger'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Upload Model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Upload extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'attachments';
   protected $fillable = ['mime', 'size', 'name', 'original_name'];
}
```

Attachment Model:

```
class Attachment extends Model
{
     public function attach()
     {
       return $this->morphTo('App\User', 'attachable');
     }
 }
```

User controller that I validated the form:

```
class UserController extends Controller

    protected function getValidator(Request $request)
    {
    $rules =  [  
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:50',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:50',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
        'phone' => 'required|numeric', //phone should be numeric

        'name' => 'required',
        'country' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'image' => 'required',
    ];

    if(request('country') == $TajikistanID) {
        $rules['province'] = 'required';
    } else {
        $rules['city'] = 'required';
    }

    return Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
}
```

Here is the registration form:

```
<form action="{{ route('users.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{csrf_field()}} //rest of input fields

    <input type="file" id="image" name="image" value="" class="form-control" />
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token()" />

</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried to look into the filesystem of laravel? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem

Comment: `doesn't work at all` is very vague. Please be more specific on what is not working

Comment: "doesn't work at all" i meant no file uploads. The rest of input fields can be inserted into table, except the file. Also doesn't throw any error message regarding file upload.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute of your file upload input field is set to `image` but in the code you are using `file` as value. Because of this laravel can't access the uploaded image.

You need to change the `name` attribute of your file upload input field to `file` like this:

```
<input type="file" id="image" name="file" value="" class="form-control" />
```

Or you dont't change the name of the file upload input element and you change your PHP code like this:

```
// Validation
$validation = Validator::make($request->all(),[
  'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg, png, jpg, gif|max:2048'
]);
```

```
// Upload
$image = $request->file('image');
```

---

A little hint for your code: Don't use HTML elements as a response for your Api. That's very ugly and not usefull. Just return the path of the image like this:

```
return response()->json([
  'message'        => 'File Uploaded Successfully',
  'uploaded_image' => '/files/' . $new_name,
  'class_name'   => 'alert-success'
]);
```

The HTML stuff is part of your frontend and not your rest API.